# How concat two sql query in a single result

Tags: mysql

I have two sql query

***First:***

```
SELECT ticketing_ticket.email,
       CONCAT(
              TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,date_create,date_close) , ' jours ',
              MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour,date_create,date_close), 24), ' heures ',
              MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute,date_create,date_close), 60), ' miinutes '
             ) AS 'temps de traitement '
FROM ticketing_ticket 
WHERE DATE(date_close) = CURDATE();
```

***Output:***

```
   |  email       |       Time
   |test@test.com | 15 jours 23 heures 7 miinutes 
   |test@test.com | 15 jours 22 heures 54 miinutes
```

***Second:***

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(T2.label SEPARATOR ';') AS 'Domaines'
FROM (
    SELECT
        @r AS _id,
        (SELECT @r := id_parent FROM ticketing_category WHERE id_category = _id) AS parent_id,
        @l := @l + 1 AS lvl
    FROM
        (SELECT @r := 38, @l := 0) vars,
        ticketing_category m
    WHERE @r <> 0) T1
JOIN ticketing_category T2
ON T1._id = T2.id_category
ORDER BY T1.lvl DESC
```

***Output:***

```
 |          Domaines           | 
 |Elections;Aides et démarches |
```

How Can i combine my sql query  in a single result like this

```
|  email       |       Time                        | Domaines           
|test@test.com |    15 jours 23 heures 7 miinutes  | Elections;Aides et démarches 
|test@test.com |    15 jours 22 heures 54 miinutes | Elections;Aides et démarches
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you can join the queries one way or another (I see no correlation so I'll assume a cross join):

```
SELECT ...
FROM (
    SELECT ticketing_ticket.email,
    CONCAT(
          TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,date_create,date_close) , ' jours ',
          MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour,date_create,date_close), 24), ' heures ',
          MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute,date_create,date_close), 60), ' miinutes '
    ) AS 'temps de traitement '
    FROM ticketing_ticket 
    WHERE DATE(date_close) = CURDATE()
) AS X
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(T2.label SEPARATOR ';') AS 'Domaines'
    FROM (
        SELECT @r AS _id,
             (SELECT @r := id_parent 
              FROM ticketing_category 
              WHERE id_category = _id) AS parent_id,
              @l := @l + 1 AS lvl
        FROM (
            SELECT @r := 38, @l := 0) vars, ticketing_category m
        WHERE @r <> 0
    ) T1
    JOIN ticketing_category T2
        ON T1._id = T2.id_category
) y;
```

Mixing old "," joins and ANSI joins makes it difficult to read the code. so I'll suggest that you remove the ";" joins:

```
SELECT ...
FROM (
    SELECT ticketing_ticket.email,
    CONCAT(
          TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,date_create,date_close) , ' jours ',
          MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour,date_create,date_close), 24), ' heures ',
          MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute,date_create,date_close), 60), ' miinutes '
    ) AS 'temps de traitement '
    FROM ticketing_ticket 
    WHERE DATE(date_close) = CURDATE()
) AS X
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(T2.label SEPARATOR ';') AS 'Domaines'
    FROM (
        SELECT @r AS _id,
             (SELECT @r := id_parent 
              FROM ticketing_category 
              WHERE id_category = _id) AS parent_id,
              @l := @l + 1 AS lvl
        FROM ( SELECT @r := 38, @l := 0) vars
        CROSS JOIN ticketing_category m
        WHERE @r <> 0
    ) T1
    JOIN ticketing_category T2
        ON T1._id = T2.id_category
) y;
```

Comment: in `SELECT @r := 38..` i want to use the `ticketing_ticket` result from the first request (alias X  in your example)

Comment: @Mercer that doesn't make sense. `ticketing_ticket` is a table. Nothing in your first result has numbers like 38. And in any case, the requirements should be **in the question**, not in comments.

Comment: @Mercer, what attribute in the first query is 38?

Comment: @Lennart is ` ticketing_ticket.id_category` but is not appear on the `select`in the first query but you can add it if it's necessary